# Import a js file from node_module inside twig

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, reveal.js, webpack-encore

I have an import issue I can't understand, but I think I'm missing something big with either webpack or Symfony and I can't find what.
I hope you can tell me.

I try to use the reveal.js module. So, using npm I added the content of this github to my node_modules: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/

Without looking at Symfony, only the index.html from the reveal.js module. There is an import line  `<script src="js/reveal.js"></script>`
If this import is missing, then an error occured: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined`

But with this import, all works fine.

If I'm telling you about this simple index.html, it's because I have the same error in my Symfony project, and I can't tell why because I think my imports are fine.
So either, my import is not ok...either the error is not the same, but I can't tell where she is.

In my webpack.config.js, I have this

```
.addEntry('js/app', [
    './assets/js/app.js',
    './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js',
    './node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './node_modules/holderjs/holder.min.js',
    './node_modules/reveal.js/lib/js/head.min.js',
    './node_modules/reveal.js/js/reveal.js'
])
```

As you can see, the reveal.js file is there, so he is concatenate into my main js file. But still, I have this `Uncaught ReferenceError: Reveal is not defined` when I try to use `<script>Reveal.initialize();</script>` inside of a twig template.

I'm really lost for this moment, so I hope you can help one way or an other, thanks :(

EDIT: In order to add some information, in my build/app.js I can see the import is there.

```
/***/ "./node_modules/reveal.js/js/reveal.js":
/*!*********************************************!*\
!*** ./node_modules/reveal.js/js/reveal.js ***!
\*********************************************/
```

Comment: Did you read a Symfony documentation about [Frontend](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)? And an example how to configure webcore with [bootstrap](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html)?

Comment: @EugeneR Yes and I already have made the import of Jquery and bootstrap. The issue is a little different I think here. I got a lead on an other forum. Someone told me, even if all the js is loaded into a single app.js. It doesn't mean I have access to it without importing. Something about ES6 modules. But really, I don't know :(